# How to use Python to connect to an Oracle database by ApacheBeam?

Tags: python, oracle, apache-beam

```
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc
    
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        result = (p
                  | 'Read from jdbc' >> ReadFromJdbc(
                    fetch_size=None,
                    table_name='table_name',
                    driver_class_name='oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
                    jdbc_url='jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl',
                    username='xxx',
                    password='xxx',
                    query='selec * from table_name'
                  )
                  |beam.Map(print)
                  )
```

When I run the above code, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Starting job service with ['java', '-jar', 'C:\\Users\\YFater/.apache_beam/cache/jars\\beam-sdks-java-extensions-schemaio-expansion-service-2.29.0.jar', '51933']
ERROR:apache_beam.utils.subprocess_server:Error bringing up service
```

Comment: Did you perform [the required setup](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/apache_beam.io.jdbc.html) (i.e., use the default expansion service or specify a custom expansion service)?

Comment: Of course, I've configured it, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Abache Beam needs to use a java expansion service in order to use JDBC from python.

You get an error because Beam cannot launch the expansion service.

To fix this, install the Java runtime in the computer where you run apache beam, and make sure `java` is in your path.

*IF* the problem persists after installing java (or if you already have it installed), probably the JAR files Beam downloaded are bad (maybe the download stopped or the file was truncated due to disk full). In that case, just remove the contents of the `$HOME/.apache_beam/cache/jars` directory and re-run the beam pipeline.

Comment: I've tried, but it still doesn't work， the following error occurs:
RuntimeError: org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.BeamSchemaInferenceException: Failed to infer Beam schema
......
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.
....
ValueError: Unsupported signal: 2

Comment: This is because you don't have the Oracle jdbc driver installed in your computer.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question again. I have installed Oracle jdbc driver on my computer, but I don't know where to put it. I tried to put it in my Apache beam environment, but I still reported the same error

Comment: The driver must be in your CLASSPATH - just put it where you find appropiate and add that directorty to the CLASSPATH variable - see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: I tried to put the driver into classpath, but the same error occurred. The system variables are set as follows：
CLASSPATH
.;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\ojdbc.jar;

Comment: You need to start a custom expansion service with extra libraries that you need in the class path. Just putting the jar in the CLASSPATH is inadequate since by default the expansion service is started using the "java -jar" command where the CLASSPATH you set is ignored.

Comment: For example, "java -cp <path1/beam-sdks-java-extensions-schemaio-expansion-service-2.29.0.jar:path2/tools.jar:path3/ojdbc.jar>' org.apache.beam.sdk.expansion.service.ExpansionService <port>    - and provide "localhost:<port>' to the 'expansion_service' field of the transform.

Answer (score 1):

Add classpath param in ReadFromJdbc

Example:
classpath=['~/.apache_beam/cache/jars/ojdbc8.jar'],